# The real difference between MEDIA_ROOT (media files) and STATIC_ROOT (static files) in python django and how to use them correctly

Tags: python, django, database, production-environment, django-staticfiles

### The real difference between MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT in python django and how to use them correctly?

I just was looking for the answer and i'm still confused about it, in the end of the day i got two different answers:

  #### - First is that the MEDIA_ROOT is for storing images and mp3 files maybe and the STATIC_ROOT for the css, js... and so on.

  #### -Second answer is that they were only using MEDIA_ROOT in the past for static files, and it caused some errors so eventually we are only using STATIC_ROOT.

is one of them right if not be direct and simple please so everybody can understand and by how to use them correctly i mean what kind of files to put in them exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding the real difference between `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` can be confusing sometimes as both of them are related to serving files.

To be clear about their differences, I could point out their uses and types of files they serve.

1. `STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS` are all used to serve the static files required for the website or application. Whereas, `MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT` are used to serve the media files uploaded by a user.

As you can see that the main difference lies between media and static files. So, let's differentiate them.

1. Static files are files like **CSS, JS, JQuery, scss, and other images(PNG, JPG, SVG, etc. )etc.** which are used in development, creation and rendering of your website or application. Whereas, media files are those files that are **uploaded by the user while using the website.**

So, if there is a JavaScript file named `main.js` which is used to give some functionalities like show popup on button click then it is a STATIC file. Similarly, images like website logo, or some static images displayed in the website that the user can't change by any action are also STATIC files.

*Hence, files(as mentioned above) that are used during the development and rendering of the website are known as STATIC files and are served by STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL or STATICFILES_DIRS(during deployment) in Django.*

*Now for the MEDIA files:* any file that the user uploads, for example; a video, or image or excel file, etc. during the normal usage of the website or application are called MEDIA files in Django.

*MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are used to point out the location of MEDIA files stored in your application.*

Hope this makes you clear.

Comment: OMG i was expecting like to be answered three days after LOL that's why i don't wanna ask but just in like 30 mins i think you were typing the answer in this time even thank you so much it's pretty clear i know now how to deal with them 